# Can we simplify Ethereum Proof-of-Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, consensus, casper, eth-2.0

I am wondering whether the protocol of Ethereum Proof-of-Stake could be simplified or not.

It seems to me that a quick simplification can be made by noticing that an **FFG vote** is redundant once a **GHOST vote** is made. Once you made a GHOST vote, you commit to one particular chain. If you are honest, the *target* and the *source* of your FFG vote will be on this same chain. And since the chain you support with the GHOST vote contains attestations, we can determine the target and source vote you would have voted (the target is the last checkpoint on this chain, and the source is the last justified checkpoint according to the attestations on that chain).

Thus, a new checkpoint will be justified at the end of an epoch if during this epoch at least 2/3 of the attesters made a GHOST vote on the same chain.

Does this simplification actually work? If yes, why use a more cumbersome method?

---

P.S. I tried asking this [question](https://ethresear.ch/t/an-other-attempt-at-simplifying-finality-in-gasper/12658) on ethresear.ch without success

Comment: This question is regarding the new Upcoming ETH version that will work on Proof-Of-Stake? Right? Because the current ETH network is Proof-Of-Work, so I don't see how this question would play to it.

Comment: Well yes, the title and the first sentence answer your question...

Comment: Good question, but a hard one. I believe there are only a handful of people who have good insight and the big picture to answer this one properly.